# how to execute shell command with piping in Elisp?

Tags: shell-command, pipe

I am trying to duplicate the following bash command in Elisp:

`curl https://google.com | readability https://google.com`

Here's what I have so far, but it doesn't capture the piping "| readability" part of it. How can I use Elisp to pass info that will be interpreted as "from stdin"?

```lisp
(shell-command-to-string (format "readability %s \n%s" url htmls))
```

Comment: I cant fathom how your elisp is supposed to be a replica for the original command.  You're not calling `curl` *at all*, there's a newline in there for some reason... your question is very confusing.

Comment: ```(shell-command-to-string (format "ls -lah %s | head -n%s" "~/" "10"))``` this works, so I'd say it's something with your call to readability, which I don't know what it is.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Cross-referencing with https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/66321/how-to-pipe-a-string-to-a-shell-command-in-elisp-rather-than-give-it-as-an-arg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell handles the pipelines, so there's no reason why the command you give `shell-command-to-string` can't include pipes.

```el
(shell-command-to-string "curl 'https://google.com' 2>/dev/null | wc")
```

Comment: The original question was really broken, but I really appreciate the 2>/dev/null, which saved my bacon when I came back for it today